# Is there a way with twilio to stop the welcoming message (Say) on the caller digit inputs and then forward it to the next IVR tree

Tags: twilio

Is there a way with twilio to stop the welcoming message (Say) once the caller input digits and then forward it to the next IVR tree without waiting the whole message ?
Thanks

Comment: Once the caller is in my tree there's the (SAY) object that I instantiated with a string.
This string takes a bit of time to finish because it's a menu where it asks the caller to push 1, or 2,  or 3.. but if the caller pushes 1 and he does not want to hear the hole message, he can not, he needs to wait until the hole message with options finishes, then the "Gather" handles the caller input digits.

Comment: What I'm in need for, is that once the caller inputs his digits he does not need to wait until he hole menu options message that I build with the "Say" to get finished, but instead he get redirected to the next servlet immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **numDigits** attribute in GATHER with a integer value.For example, one might set 'numDigits' to '5' and ask the caller to enter a 5 digit zip code. When the caller enters the fifth digit of '94117', Twilio will immediately submit the data to the 'action' URL.

Check detail on [Twilio Docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-digits).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather timeout="10" numDigits="5">
        <Say>Please enter your pin number and then press star.</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Comment: Hey Rubai, thanks for helping out in the community. If you'd like a 'thank you' shirt from Twilio please email Megan, mspeir@twilio.com. Cheers!

Comment: Actually not, it does not resolve the issue.
I'm only using 1 Digit and the caller needs to wait the hole message before the app takes into account his input and redirect him to another servlet.

Comment: For one digit, you should use **numDigits="1"**. Can you please paste your XML response here?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the Gather after the Say. Instead I should've wraped the Gather around the say:

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice" language="it-IT">...</Say>
    <Gather method="POST" numDigits="1" action="/twilio/ServletHandleUserInput" finishOnKey="0">
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

So I amended it alike :

```
<Response>
<Gather method="POST" numDigits="1" action="/twilio/ServletHandleUserInput" finishOnKey="0">
<Say voice="alice" language="it-IT">...</Say>
</Gather></Response>
```

Thanks Rubai